# create table without specifying in db/migrate rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

I have following structure of my article.rb model in rails

```
 property :artikelnummer, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'
 property :eannummer, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'

 property :bezeichnung, type: 'multi_field', fields: {
bezeichnung: {type: 'string'},
ngram: {:type => 'string', :index_analyzer => 'ngram_index_analyzer', :search_analyzer => 'ngram_search_analyzer'},
suggest: {:type => 'string', :analyzer => 'suggest_analyzer'}
}

  property :bezeichnung_zusatz, type: 'multi_field', fields: {
bezeichnung_zusatz: {type: 'string'},
ngram: {:type => 'string', :index_analyzer => 'ngram_index_analyzer', :search_analyzer => 'ngram_search_analyzer'}
  }

  property :matchcode, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'

  property :mengeneinheit, type: 'string', include_in_all: false

  property :gewicht, type: 'float', include_in_all: false

  property :hersteller, type: 'multi_field', fields: {
hersteller: {type: 'string'},
unchanged: {type: 'string', :index => 'not_analyzed'},
ngram: {:type => 'string', :index_analyzer => 'ngram_index_analyzer', :search_analyzer => 'ngram_search_analyzer'}
  }

  property :hersteller_nummer, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed', include_in_all: false

  property :hersteller_artikelnummer, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'

  property :gruppe, type: 'multi_field', fields: {
gruppe: {type: 'string'},
ngram: {:type => 'string', :index_analyzer => 'ngram_index_analyzer', :search_analyzer => 'ngram_search_analyzer'}
  }

  property :gruppe_zusatz, type: 'multi_field', fields: {
gruppe_zusatz: {type: 'string'},
ngram: {:type => 'string', :index_analyzer => 'ngram_index_analyzer', :search_analyzer => 'ngram_search_analyzer'}
  }

  property :gruppe_nummer, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed', include_in_all: false

 #property :hauptgruppe, type: 'multi_field', fields: {
 #  hauptgruppe: {type: 'string'},
```

#  ngram: {:type => 'string', :index_analyzer => 'ngram_index_analyzer', :search_analyzer => 'ngram_search_analyzer'}
     #}

```
 # TODO: n-level facet
  property :hierarchie, type: 'multi_field', fields: {
hierarchie: {type: 'string', index_analyzer: 'hierarchie_index_analyzer', search_analyzer: 'keyword', include_in_all: false},
ngram: {type: 'string', index_analyzer: 'ngram_index_analyzer', search_analyzer: 'ngram_search_analyzer'}
   }

  property :langtext, type: 'multi_field', fields: {
langtext: {type: 'string'},
ngram: {:type => 'string', :index_analyzer => 'ngram_index_analyzer', :search_analyzer => 'ngram_search_analyzer'}
 }

  property :infotext, type: 'multi_field', fields: {
infotext: {type: 'string'},
ngram: {:type => 'string', :index_analyzer => 'ngram_index_analyzer', :search_analyzer => 'ngram_search_analyzer'}
 }

    property :bestelltext, type: 'multi_field', fields: {
bestelltext: {type: 'string'},
ngram: {:type => 'string', :index_analyzer => 'ngram_index_analyzer', :search_analyzer => 'ngram_search_analyzer'}
```

}

```
    property :dimension, type: 'string', include_in_all: false

    property :listenpreis_netto, type: 'float', index: 'not_analyzed', include_in_all: false

   property :listenpreis_brutto, type: 'float', index: 'not_analyzed', include_in_all: false
```

is there any way to create table based on above information migration file does not exist in db/migrations..
if yes then how it can be done

thanks in advance

**edit** *most simple way i can ask*

> *i want above information in my database how can i do it*

Comment: Is it possible it using mongo-db!!

Comment: OR any other database!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with using Mongo in ActiveRecord.  (Mongoid?); however I do use Mongo using the raw Ruby gem.  In Mongo there's no notion of a schema (with fixed table/columns); rather mongo collections and documents spring into existence when you write these.  So I'm not sure what you would really do with migrations.  Perhaps use these to prefill collections?

Comment: except mongodb i can use mysql or sqlite3 but what about tables?? Should I create by add migration and above mentioned fields let me know...

Comment: Mongo is a non-sql database.  It doesn't have a traditional sql notion of fixed defined tables and columns.  It's basically json documents.

Comment: plz see my first comment i can use any db or simple how can create db based on above information